# android textView not whole appear

Tags: android

i have a textView,its height is fixed,and the Text characters sum is not uncertain,

```
 <TextView  
android:id="@+id/item_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="30dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:textColor="#000000" 
/>
```

but when the Text height >  the height of textView,in the last line  The lower part oftext  characters is cutted

as https://i.stack.imgur.com/qca9C.jpg and http://i.6.cn/cvbnm/5e/b7/41/f929ffab5b4e007e6e643ef5340325eb.jpg which is use red pen mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pls tru by setting height as wrap_content rather than fill_parent.

```
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/item_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:textColor="#000000" 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

HI..Try this

```
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/item_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:textColor="#000000" 
/>
```

Comment: i test it ,but Still as the same as before